# SQL - select an increment value or return a constant

Tags: mysql, sql, select, null, union

So what I need to do is to select the maximum of column (and increment it with 1 each time) and if this value is null (which will be the case for the first occurence) I must return the constant 0 (which will be the max for the next occurence).

My goal is to do something like this :

```
SELECT (Max(id) + 1) FROM my_table WHERE id IS NOT NULL
UNION
SELECT 0 FROM my_table WHERE id IS NULL
```

However that does not work. What can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way your query is written, it will return two rows. One for the first query, and one after the union.

If you only want a single row, you can just use the MAX() function. If the table is empty, the MAX() function returns null. An option you have then is to use COALESCE() in your select statement, which returns the first non null value. In other words this query:

```
SELECT COALESCE(MAX(id) + 1, 0) AS maxID
FROM myTable;
```

Could be explained as: Give me the maximum ID from the table. If the table was empty, just return 0.

Here is a [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ba4a8/1) example with an empty table and a non-empty table.

Comment: Nice explanation that did the trick !  and thanks for the fiddle link (no doubt that this will be helpful for a future use)

Comment: @maher.belkh not a problem. And yes, SQL Fiddle is very helpful for sharing database help, especially on this site.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
SELECT COALESCE(Max(id + 1), 0) FROM my_table WHERE id IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: This is a good solution. It can be improved though by dropping the `WHERE id IS NOT NULL` because your coalesce function handles that, so it becomes redundant.

Comment: It's true, i have blind copy\pasted it like author's  business rule

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT (MAX(CASE WHEN id IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE id END) + 1) FROM my_table
```